# Temporary radiator removal setup

Tags: radiator

If I want to remove a radiator for a few days or a week but did want the heat to work during that time, is it okay to simply cap the pipe stubs or is it better to simulate a radiator with a piece of pipe that connects the two? Obviously, the latter option is more labor and material intensive but does it make sense to do it? It is one of the seven radiators in the house.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the layout of the heating circuits. Some systems would cease to work (everywhere) if one radiator was removed, as they are all in series. Or at least all the ones on that circuit would stop working.

Others would not be affected as they are not. You can probably tell by just closing the valve on it (if it has one) and seeing if the heat stops working elsewhere.

If it does not have a valve,, that might indicate the series situation as being more likely. The only valves on the series layout I live with are air bleeder valves, and a shutoff near the boiler in the basement.

Answer (score 1):

If your radiator has a valve on it, it means the radiator can be turned off without affecting the rest of the system. [This blog post](https://plumbhq.uk/blogs/blog/your-central-heating-system-explained) has a really good diagram to explain why.

I have heard of people getting a 1/2" BSP nut and capping off the radiator valve on the tails. Use lots of PTFE tape and make sure you test your fix before you walk off and don't think about it again for a week!!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: A linked diagram us useless. This is supposed to be an answer

Comment: i tried shutting the rad valve but it leaked anyway

Comment: If you are affiliated **in any way** with the site that you linked to, you **must** disclose that affiliation. Please see the [expected behavior](/help/behavior), [product support](/help/product-support) and [promotion](/help/promotion) pages in the [help] for more information.